# При попытке войти на ruSO через Яндекс получаю ошибку, как исправить?

Tags: поддержка, способы-входа

*Этот вопрос меня попросил задать знакомый, который сам не может залогиниться.*

При попытке войти на ruSO через привязку Яндекса стал получать ошибку

```
400
Неизвестно приложение с таким client_id
```

При попытке восстановить учетную запись через почту Яндекса, пишет что нет привязанного аккаунта к этой почте. Какие есть варианты вернуть свою учетную запись, если постоянно входил только через вход Яндекса?